# Apacheの公開範囲について

Tags: apache

つい先日よりPHPを始めた初心者です。
現在XAMPPを使ってPHPの勉強を行っているのですが、Apacheの公開範囲が分からずに困っています。
デフォルトのまま使っていると、他者からの（ローカル環境以外）アクセスが可能になっている状態なのでしょうか？
また、ローカル環境のみで使えるようにする場合はどのようにしたらよろしいのでしょうか。
自分で調べた範囲では、httpd.confのListenに自身のipアドレスを追記するとよいと見たのですが、それを行ったところ、localhostでのApacheのサイトへもアクセスできなくなってしまいました。
この点に関しても、回答をいただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamppを公開するとなったらルータの設定やファイアウォールの設定を変更する必要がありますが、こちらをしていなければローカル以外からアクセスが可能になることはないでしょう。

ListenでローカルからのIPアドレスの追加はIPv4であれば

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

で問題ないと思います。

```
Listen [::1]:80
```

詳しくは以下のApacheのリファレンスを参考にしてください。
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/bind.html